# React Web App to static website using gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a react-web-app using webpack and npm (create-react-app to be precise).
My target is to convert it to a static website using **gatsby**(or some other static site generator?).

How can I achieve this?

Do I have a better option(other than from **gatsby**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby is a fine option, you can learn more about it here: https://kalinchernev.github.io/learn-gatsbyjs/

Comment: Link was helpful. I can update the site content without another build? or graphql can be used to add _just a little_ dynamic behavior to the generated build ?

Comment: Gatsby generates its static content at build time. If you want to add some dynamic content to be pulled in on page load, that's also possible